# Will there be complete windows transparency management in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: unity, gnome, 18.04, window, transparency

I am a huge fan of Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity Desktop Manager allowing to customize plenty of things with Compiz Config Settings Manager (CCSM), among many many others, I name the windows transparency! :D

Unfortunately, except maybe for window "frame" transparency, I see no possibility (searched a lot on Ask Ubuntu) to configure full window transparency in Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome Desktop Environment as described here for former Ubuntu versions (Ubuntu 16.04/18.04 Unity: works; Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome: doesn't work; Ubuntu 18.04 default: doesn't work): https://www.howtogeek.com/167674/how-to-enable-and-tweak-ubuntus-flashy-graphical-effects/  :(

Hence, will there be some way to manage windows transparency in Ubuntu 18.04 running Gnome Desktop Environment (integrated or with the help of tweaking tools)?

Comment: Can't tell, probably the gnome developpers will know. Did you check the Gnome Shell extension "Glassy GNOME"? This extension allows to set some transparency to Gnome Shell.

Comment: Thank you for your input, however I'd prefer to have an integrated solution which comes bundled with Ubuntu for portability, compatibility and security reasons.

Comment: Again, thank you, I checked the extension under Ubuntu/Gnome and it's easy to install. Configuring is still tinkering with the command line, however a GUI is on the road map, so hope remains. :)